# Is it a good idea to have a wireless connected Subwoofer for Vinyl?

Tags: vinyl, sound-quality, turntable, streaming

Very similar question like [Is it a good idea to stream a vinyl turntable via Bluetooth?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/6392/is-it-a-good-idea-to-stream-a-vinyl-turntable-via-bluetooth) but with a wireless connected Subwoofer.

I soon own a [HT-G700 3.1ch Dolby Atmos® / DTS:X® Soundbar](https://electronics.sony.com/audio/soundbars/all-soundbars/p/htg700) sound system, the connection to Subwoofer is wireless.

> Wireless subwoofer delivers powerful bass sound

I assume the same answers apply? The question is identical, or is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a technical level, yes it's the same question. But the subwoofer reproduces the very lowest sounds only. It might be a little odd to have only the subwoofer on wireless--for one thing it might have a little lag that the wired speakers wouldn't--but if the important thing to you was to hear the singer's voice (for instance) in a pure analog form, you could probably still have that.

EDIT - As noted in the comments, the time lag between the subwoofer and the wired speakers would probably be significant enough to **noticeably degrade the listening experience.**

Comment: If everything's wireless, it can renegotiate a predelay [if the overall system's smart enough] Otherwise, yeah, phase/delay issues. Avoid.

Comment: All you need is the tiniest amount of delay to cause phase issues and a temporal smearing of transients. If the speakers and sub are producing any of the same frequency range, that could cause further unwanted colourisation. So yeah, I'd say it would cause noticeable issues. But I'm 100% wires, I don't get why anybody would pay _more_ to get _less_ accurate sound, so probably not the most unbiased perspective :)